# Parent Key not found (ORA-02291)

Tags: sql, jpa, oracle11g, spring-data, jhipster

In my User object I have below join table:

```
@JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "JHI_USER_AUTHORITY",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authority_name", referencedColumnName = "name")})
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
```

I also have a trigger on User object to insert an primary id up on row creation

```
TRIGGER TRG_JHI_USER_ID
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON JHI_USER
            FOR EACH ROW
            DECLARE
            BEGIN
            SELECT SEQ_USER.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
            END TRG_JHI_USER_ID;
```

Now when I create an User I get below exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (PORTALUSER.FK_USER_ID) violated - parent key not found
```

Seems like when the User object is tried to be persisted it persist my many-to-many table too before the trigger is executed yet thus no user_id found, if that is correct understood. How do I solve this without digging in a complex solution ?

This happen in Oracle 11.

This is the model:

[image]

Comment: The "portaluser" is the owner like "PORTALUSER"."JHI_USER_AUTHORITY".

Comment: I have added the model in my description

Comment: Sorry for my confusion on what `portaluser` was.  Still, the trigger is not the concern.  Somehow, the `jhi_user_authority` row is being inserted *before* the parent `jhi_user` row. Do you have control over that? Are you even sure that a `jhi_user` row is being inserted?

Comment: My controller populates a new user object and using JPA repository to save the the user which should persist the referenced many-to-many object too. Does the model help ?

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, both the `jhi_user` and `jhi_user_authority` rows are persisted by the same code/transaction?  If so, I'm not clear on what `jhi_user_authority.user_id` value you are trying to insert and how it can possibly be correct.  Because the `JHI_USER`'s `ID` value is set by the insert trigger, how does your code know what that value is so that it can set it correctly during the insert of the `jhi_user_authority` row?

Comment: You are correct. Due to both tables are executed in on transaction by JPA. Maybe the trigger is late updating the ID of the jhi_user and thus no parent key found. I just wish to still make it work in one transaction keeping my JPA many-to-many join definition and some way postpone the inserting of jhi_user_authority.user_id.

Comment: It's not just that the trigger is late. Even if it wasn't, how would the insert of the `jhi_user_authority` row know about the `user_id` being set by the trigger?  You would have to query the database right after the insert of the `jhi_user` row to obtain that information. Personally, I would drop the trigger, and have the code query the `SEQ_USER` sequence directly to obtain the new `user_id`, so that you can set it correctly up-front in both your entities to be inserted.

Comment: What if I use jpa.flush before saving the user (commit) whould that help ? The solution works without the trigger in H2 db due the Id has default value to a seq. But that is not possible in the oracle 11 which require the trigger. My jpa jointable annotation makes sure that the referenced objects are propagated.

Answer (score 1):

JHipster only supports Oracle 12.

The only configuration you could have selected with JHipster for Oracle support is `Oracle 12c`, which implies it's not going to work well for Oracle 11.

Please note it's very hard for an Open Source project to support a proprietary, paying database, so we are not going to work on older versions of Oracle.

Comment: Ok, thanks Julien :) Btw, I'm currently using the solution mentioned in https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1631